# How to use glCopyImageSubData with GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP texture?

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

If I create two textures as
1. srcID
2. destID

Both of type GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP

> glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 6, GL_RGBA8, 32, 32);

Now "srcID" is filled with all the texture data required.
So what parameters be used in order to copy entire "srcID" to "destID".
Tried many combinations but it always gave error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, and purely from studying the man page and spec document:

```
glCopyImageSubData(srcID, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                   destID, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                   32, 32, 6);
```

The least obvious part is how to specify that you want to copy all cubemap faces. The spec says about the target arguments:

> All non-proxy texture targets are accepted, with the exception of TEXTURE_BUFFER and the cubemap face selectors described in table 8.19.

This tells me that `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` must be used for those arguments, not specific faces.

Then on how to specify that you want to copy all 6 cubemap faces, this part is relevant (highlight added by me):

> Slices of a one-dimensional array, two-dimensional array, cube map array, or three dimensional texture, or **faces of a cube map** texture are all compatible provided they share a compatible internal format, and **multiple** slices or **faces may be copied** between these objects with a single call **by specifying the starting slice with srcZ and dstZ**, and the number of slices to be copied with srcDepth. **Cubemap textures always have six faces which are selected by a zero-based face index**, according to the order speciﬁed in table 8.19.

So copying all 6 faces should work with using 0 for `srcZ` and `dstZ`, and 6 for `srcDepth`.